# Как правильно писать слово "фандебобер"?

Tags: этимология, орфография

Пожалуйста, ответьте на вопрс, откуда произошло слово "фандебобер" и как правильно его писать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно писать - кандибобер. Читать так же.

КАНДИБО́БЕР, кандибобера, муж. только в выражении: с кандибобером (прост. шутл. фам.) - лихо, отлично, на славу. Проплясал с шиком, с кандибобером.
(Ушаков)

Здесь, видимо, не все значения. Можно указать - с шумом, со скандалом, с апломбом и т.п.
А также - очень дорогой, пижонский ("сапоги с кандибобером"), "пафосно" - ругался с кандибобером и т.д.

Происхождение неясно. 
Вот [тут](http://coollingua.blogspot.com/2010/06/blog-post_30.html) - большая статья, но неавторитено.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылочку!